# Default display style of a page designed using bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am playing with some bootstrap-styled page and come to the following example:

http://htmlstream.com/preview/unify-v1.5/

There is a button on top right corner that can switch between "wide" and "boxed" layout. And I want the page to start with "boxed" layout, without the need of click it by user.

I have gone through the css, there is an item named ".boxed-layout". I tried to add `class="boxed-layout"` in `body`, but I can see the view changed.

I am newbie on CSS, can anyone inspire me on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add class `container` also in the body tag along with `boxed-layout`. So you will have:

```
<body class="boxed-layout container">
```

Comment: thanks! mind to tell me how do you know that `container` need to be added in class also?

Comment: Used firebug to inspect the page.

Comment: I used google chrome and inspect the element, what should I look for? `body`?

Comment: I recommend you start using Firefox insted of Chrome. I know Chrome is a little bit faster, but Firefox has the best plugins for developers. Firebug from Firefox is way better than inspect element from Chrome. If you open that page with firefox and open firebug plugin, you will see the html structure and while you toogle between boxed on wide, you will see the body tag class is being updated or removed. It's very simple.